# PuTTY PSFTP returning error: unknown command "´╗┐cd"

Tags: batch-file, utf-8, putty, byte-order-mark, psftp

HI I am running below command from my Windows server. I have got private key added so authentication wise it is fine. But when ever I am running the command getting a weird issue

```
psftp user@host -b FTPfile.txt
```

The file FTPfile.txt has only two lines.

```
cd /apps/scripts/batch/sln/input
put Test.txt
```

But I am getting error `psftp: unknown command "´╗┐cd"`

[image]

And I noticed any command given in the first line of the file returns a similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `FTPfile.txt` starts with a Unicode [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (U+FEFF) encoded in UTF-8, which corresponds to the bytes 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF. psftp thinks those bytes are part of the command name. When it prints those bytes to the console as part of the error message, they're interpreted according to [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), which makes it look like `´╗┐`.

To fix this, you need to get rid of the BOM. How did you create `FTPfile.txt`? Windows text editors usually have a setting to change the encoding of a file to "ANSI" (plain ASCII would also work).

Comment: thanks a lot. You have pointed out exact issue. It solved the problem.